# Django's Content Type framework does not trigger Cascade delete

Tags: python, django, cascade, django-contenttypes

Suppose the following models:

```
class DeltaCheck(models.Model):
    logs = generic.GenericRelation('Log')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Log(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

If I create a DeltaCheck and a couple of Logs and then delete the DeltaCheck, the Logs are deleted as well:

```
In [7]: Log.objects.count()
Out[7]: 10

In [8]: DeltaCheck.objects.get().delete()

In [9]: Log.objects.count()
Out[9]: 0
```

BUT if I delete the User (the field `owner`), the `DeltaCheck` gets deleted BUT not the Logs, look:

```
In [14]: Log.objects.count()
Out[14]: 10

In [15]: DeltaCheck.objects.get().owner.delete()

In [16]: DeltaCheck.objects.all()
Out[16]: []

In [17]: Log.objects.count()
Out[17]: 10
```

Why is that? Seems like a bug.

EDIT 1:

Curiously,  both pre_delete and post_delete signals are fired in the failing case... What happens in the middle?

EDIT 2:

Ok this is weird as heck. If I define an EMPTY receiver for the `pre_delete` signal... it works :/ Just added:

```
@receiver(pre_delete)
def recv(**kwargs):
    pass
```

And now it works...

Comment: Having spent 30 seconds on the subject, it does sound like a bug. Especially because the fact that a reverse generic relation gets deleted is purely a useful utility / outside the usual ORM behavior in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I've opened a ticket in the official bug tracker https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22594 For now I'll be deleting those guys within the signal receiver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the bug report states](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22594#comment:5), it was certainly a bug that has now been fixed.